# Unity3d Rotate Around to certain point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that can rotate around a sphere. Basically I need to move object from initial position to new position (From V1 to V2) using RotateAround. V1 is initial position and V2 is position that can be anywhere around the sphere. I have value of both Vectors so I can calculate angle with Vector3.Angle() but I don't know how to calculate proper axis to use in RotateAround() method.

[image]

Comment: it's possible `LookAt` can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Vector3.up](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-up.html) or [Transform.up](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-up.html) as in [example](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)

#### EDIT:

I think I get it. Assuming that `V1` and `V2` have the same length: Just find new vector perpendicular to this vectors using [Vector3.cross](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html)

Comment: And what if the destination point is more north or more south?

Comment: What do you mean north or south? Destination points depends on point you rotate around, axis and angle.

Comment: I need to move object to certain point, not to some random direction. I edited my question, maybe now it's more clear.

Comment: Thats what I'm talking about! It solves my problem. Dzięki pozdrawiam ;)

Comment: I don't get it, can you provide a more detailed answer?

Comment: Sure: Powderek wanted to rotate point around sphere, to be more specific: around axis that goes through center of sphere and is perpendicular  to `V1` and `V2`. It can be computed with `Vector3.cross`. From link: we have `a=V1` and `b=V2`. The the result axis will be used in https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html